# How will SQL Server query a table partitioned using a calculated field if the predicate col is a factor in the field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning

Imagine you have table *t* where statusID is a calculated field based on status. 'Live'=1, 'Deleted'=2 and so on.  *t* is partitioned by statusID meaning that all 1 goes into a partition, all 2 goes into another etc.   Now let's query *t*.  If I want all live records can I use `WHERE status='live'` or must I use `where statusID=1` to take advantage of the partition?

| ID | val1 | val2 | status | statusID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | ABC | live | 1 |
| 2 | xyz | XYZ | deleted | 2 |
| 3 | foo | BAR | archived | 3 |

We have some existing tables which are getting quite large, and code that leverages the status col, which is indexed.  For most loads this is fine, but with the rows getting into the millions we are starting to see issues with joins.

Comment: Why not just try it and inspect the execution plan?

Comment: @Dale K - the table is not yet partitioned and I would rather not go through that hassle for a 2m row table.   I will off course test if nobody knows off hand.

Comment: Well, for any change of this magnitude, I personally would be testing on a dev box.

Comment: To take advantage of the partition, you need to use the partitioning column in the `where` clause.

Comment: The first step should be to understand what is causing your issues. A couple millions rows is a trivial number for most modern database engines.

Comment: @SMor if it was a standalone table I would agree but there are several of them that have to be joined for reports as well as UI transactions so I’m trying to get ahead of it as these tables are growing fairly rapidly.